# Update a field of all elements in react functional state

Tags: reactjs, iteration, state

My state is

```
  const [ formInputsProperty, setFormInputsProperty ] = useState(
    [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "courseTitle",
        type: "text",
        placeholder: "Course Title",
        errorMessage: "Course Title should be 3-16 characters and shouldn't include any special character!",
        label: "Course Title",
        pattern: "^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}$",
        required: true,
        isFocused: false
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "shortDesc",
        type: "text",
        placeholder: "Course Short Description",
        errorMessage: "Course Description should be 10-50 characters and shouldn't include any special character!",
        label: "Course Short Description",
        pattern: "^[A-Za-z0-9]{10,50}$",
        required: true,
        isFocused: false
      }
    ]
  )
```

Now i want to update isFocused to true of all elements of the given state. How can I do that? I tried map but was not successfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the map function and then setting the state afterwards.

Example:

```
const updateFocus = () => {
    setFormInputsProperty((prev) => (
        prev.map((item) => ({...item, isFocused: true}))
    );
};
```

Explanation:
You access the current state with `prev` and then use the `map` function on it. With `map` you iterate over every element in the list and can do what ever you want with it. In this case we just set the `isFocused` property to true. The return value inside the `map` function always replaces the current item.

[More information on MDN about map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[More information on MDN about spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thx, your solution works. You missed just a closing first bracket. 

setFormInputsProperty((prev) => (
      prev.map((item) => ({...item, isFocused: true}))
    )); => here will be two closing first brackets.